# Upcoming UI Conferences we should promote StackExchange UI at?

Tags: discussion, promotion

What are some upcoming UI conferences that we could use to draw attention to UI StackExchange? Should we attend simply to profile this community, or are members already attending and willing to spend some additional effort on getting the UI community into the spotlight?